# Why does this gradient not cover the entire element?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, gradient

I have the following CSS:

```
<a class="button">
    <span>Y</span>
</a>

    .button {
        -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
        -moz-border-left-colors: none;
        -moz-border-right-colors: none;
        -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #206CAF;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #206CAF;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1)),color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #206CAF;
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(top,rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 100%);
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    border-style: none none solid;
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.15);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 12px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

When on chrome and safari (mac and windows) and IE 9 (windows), the entire box doesn't get covered by the gradient and there is some white space at the bottom.  Is there something wrong in my code or is that how it should look?

See fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/VmTks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discrepancy between IE/Chrome/Safari and Firefox is caused by this rule:

`border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);`

You need to remove the `-moz` prefixed properties and the behaviour will be consistent across browsers. Chrome, Safari (and I assume IE) were unsurprisingly rendering that rule as invalid. You can see this in Chrome's developer tools by the `border-color` property having a strike-through.

http://jsfiddle.net/VmTks/4/

Comment: Ahh.... hence my border none removed it. How did you see that Chrome declares it as invalid.

Comment: Chrome dev. tools - you'll see the cross-out for the `border-color` property

Comment: I see. I thought it only crossed out declarations that were superseded, not ones ignored. Nice to know. So he had set border non, but only used the vendor prefix for some reason.

Comment: It's worth noting that borders inherit their color from the text by default.  Unless the parent element has a border on it, you could specify `border-color: inherit inherit rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);`

Answer (score 2):

I added `border-bottom: none` and it fixed it for me. When I removed your color declaration I saw it removed the white bar so I figured it had to do with the text somehow. I'm not sure exactly why, but I just messed with different ones until I was removed. I thought it was underline at first, but I saw that was already there.

Comment: Do you mean this: -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;

Comment: I don't know why you are declaring it that way. if you want no borders just do: `border: none;`. Why the `-moz-` prefix? And divs don't have a border by default, so why declare anything at all. You can declare border-radius without color, image, style, or width I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this line

```
background: linear-gradient(top,
```

should be

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,
```

but I'm not 100% certain - apologies if not!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient